# git rename directory with unversioned files

Tags: git

Example situation:
dev environment with a folder called "test", which contains only a .gitignore file;
prod environment with tons of git-ignored images in that folder.

What's needed:
rename "test" into "something-else", while keeping the unversioned files in "something-else".

In reality:
`git mv test something-else` creates a new directory called "something-else" with the .gitignore file in it, but leaves the old "test" folder with all the images inside it alone.

Any solutions?

Comment: `git mv test something-else && mv test/* test/.[^.]* something-else/` perhaps?

Comment: `mv test/* test/.[^.]*` - why the second part?

Comment: It moves hidden files like `.htaccess`: Files starting with `.` and then something else than a `.`: `[^.]`. It's a bash feature.

Comment: You can just move the directory in git, pull in the production environment and move the files from the directory in the production environment. I don't think you can tell git to move those files.

Comment: @Boldewyn well, that's not a GIT command though...

Comment: @dtech I know, but sometimes it's not possible, if you don't have access to all production environments. I work on a project that has many clients, all of which have repo read access, but we don't have access to their terminals.

Comment: @jurchiks you can make it one with [aliases](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases), if that is your unexpressed requirement.

Comment: @Boldewyn I mean it's not a *standard* GIT command... If I have no access to client production environments, then aliases are not an option.